# StringBuilder appends Persian Numbers

Tags: c#, .net, stringbuilder

I'm trying to append some numbers to a string, that string already contains Persian character and `StringBuilder` always appends Persian number to the string.

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append( other things );
    sb.Append("', '");
    sb.Append("1234234");
    sb.Append("', ");
```

Even when I'm explicitly using English numbers like ones in the above code, I still end up with Persian numbers. How can I append English numbers to this string?

**UPDATE**

These lines simulate my problem, you can see the Persian number by tracing this code:

```
     StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();
                    temp.Append("INSERT INTO [db] (....) VALUES ('21211221', 111555, 
                                '2015/12/12', 'نام خانوادگی  ', 'اتاق چهار تخته");
                temp.Append("', '");
                temp.Append("234234");
```

The last append should be an English number, but it's not.

Comment: That seems unlikely. It's possible that whatever you're using to *render* the string is getting confused though. Please post a short but complete program demonstrating the problem - and diagnose the *real* contents of the string by displaying the UTF-16 value of each character in it (basically cast each `char` to `int`.)

Comment: You should post a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. That short but complete program shouldn't need to hit a database at all. It's also not at all clear where you're seeing the problem...

Comment: You still haven't said where you're observing the Persian number. Are you writing it into the console? Seeing it in the debugger? Seeing it in whatever tool you use to view your database contents? (It would also help if you'd cut the example down to a bear minimum. I'd also **strongly** recommend using parameterized SQL rather than building the SQL dynamically like this, btw.)

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't reproduce for me. As a side-note, you might want to consider using parameters in queries rather than putting the values directly in the SQL text. And since you're apparently using `varchar` literals (rather than `nvarchar`), I don't see how .NET could have anything to do with the persian numbers in your database.

Comment: I'm seeing it in the debugger. And if I insert them in the database, they will be question marks, I can see it by MS SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: I'm building a string for all of the records, and trying to insert them at once, so I don't think I can use parameters.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the `string` overload of `Append`? If you use the `int` overload, it will use your current culture for formatting.

Comment: یه کم گنگ مثال دادی . ، یه کم دقیق تر بگو . اعداد فارسی رو کجا وارد کردی

Comment: @Ali I don't have any Persian number, they're all in English, but I do have Persian text.

Comment: @Luaan, they variable is string, and for testing I've tried explicit strings like `"234234"`. How can I be sure that I'm using the `string` overload?

Comment: Well, if you're passing a string literal or a string local, it's using the string overload. Also, if you mouse over the method name in Visual Studio, it will show you which overload it's using. What happens if you do the same append to a `StringBuilder` that *doesn't* have any persian characters? Is there really a difference? `Append` doesn't really do anything *but* slam the characters together. There's no transformations whatsoever.

Comment: @JonSkeet, can you see the same in the debugger. Can I set the culture in class library project?

Comment: @Luaan, I just tried it with English text, and it was fine, I got English numbers. There is a thing: it doesn't always happen! I have other Persian records, and their numbers are appending normally and in English.

Comment: You can add `temp.Append('\x200E');` right after `temp.Append("INSERT..`

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov, Wonderfully, it works! Why?

Comment: @Akbari Renderer becomes confused about RTL and LTR order. You help it by specifying that it should use LTR order after persian letters. 'U+200E' - it is Unicode Left-to-right symbol.

Comment: Please post your answer :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @Jon-Skeet said, it is a problem of renderer. Windows text rendering engine becomes confused after getting persian characters and continues to append following text in RTL order. Thus we need to help renderer to proper render appended text in LTR order. For that we can append Unicode Left-to-right symbol 'U+200E' after persian text.

```
StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();
temp.Append("INSERT INTO [db] (....) VALUES ('21211221', 111555, '2015/12/12', 'نام خانوادگی  ', 'اتاق چهار تخته");
temp.Append('\x200E');
temp.Append("', '");
temp.Append("234234");
```

Without LTR symbol:

```
INSERT INTO [db] (....) VALUES ('21211221', 111555, '2015/12/12', 'نام خانوادگی ', 'اتاق چهار تخته', '234234
```

With LTR symbol:

```
INSERT INTO [db] (....) VALUES ('21211221', 111555, '2015/12/12', 'نام خانوادگی ', 'اتاق چهار تخته‎', '234234
```

Comment: But it wasn't just a render problem, those number would have been saved in the database that way.

Comment: @Akbari Because fields were reordered, compare two outputs in edit. It would be better to use parameterized query to not have such problem from the beginning.